# Convert gwt project into maven gwt project

Tags: gwt, maven

I want to convert a gwt project to a maven project. I did configure->convert to maven. That just created pom.xml and target folder inside my project. The folder structure remains the same because maven project structure is src->main->java. And then I want to create a war file, can anyone help me to do this work.

Comment: I have existing whole gwt application created already now I want to convert it to maven .In the link that you have provided they are using Archetype which is creating the maven project i dont want that.

Comment: As i have mentioned there is no automagic solution for this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You do not have fully AUTOMagic solution for this.**

### Steps after Configure->Convert to maven

1) Identify each library jar and version used in the project and add a corresponding dependency section for it in maven pom.

2) Create a build section in your pom and you can specify any folder structure ( suggesting you to prefer src/main/java

3) Add relevant plugins section under build for gwt compilation. Use gwt sample projects as templates.

4) Lots of copy/paste between folders ( if you migrate to maven' src/main/java ). Use Eclipse refactor feature to avoid manual visit to each file.

Stick the GWT sample projects approach for maven pom files. It's easier to troubleshoot with FAQ on the GWT Dev section for Maven and GPE plugin.

**Update** - Semi Automated solution

- I came across a concept of automatic maven pom generation called
  [tera-form](http://code.google.com/p/teraform-mvn/).
- [Google Groups discussion on this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gwt-steering/RNDuj74LblQ)

Answer (score 0):

I would use an archetype to create a new maven project with everything set. Then copy all your source files to the `src/main/java` folder and your tests to the `src/test/java`.

Normally I use the `gwtquery` archetype, but you could use any other or the official `webAppCreator` distributed with the gwt sdk.

```
mvn archetype:generate  \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=com.googlecode.gwtquery \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=gquery-archetype  \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.2.0 \
    -DgroupId=com.mycompany \
    -DartifactId=myproject \
    -DprojectName=MyProject 


webAppCreator -noant -maven -overwrite \
    -out myproject \
     com.mycompany.MyProject
```